# How to create multi tasks each one in a separate thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, wxwidgets

I have two static methods:

- `bool getPicture(const std::string url, const std::string keywords ="")`
- `bool showPicture(wxStaticBitmap *viewer)`

Those methods each one does a separate task, so, I want each one to be executed in a separate thread.

```
#include <wx/thread.h>

// Declaration

class CThread : public wxThread {
public:
    CThread() = default;
    ~CThread() = default;
    void *Entry();
};

// Implementation

void* CThread::Entry() {
    CPublic::getPicture(mainFrm::getInstance()->targetURL, CPublic::getConfigItem("settings/keywords").ToStdString());
    // CPublic::showPicture(mainFrm::getInstance()->viewer_btmp);
    return 0;
}

// Create an instance

wxThread *th = new CThread();
th->Create();
th->Run();
```

As you seen in the previous code, there's one an `Entry()` method in each thread class, so, I want another an `Entry()` method to put my next method `showPicture()` into it.

**Do I have to create another class which has another** `Entry()` **method to put my** `showPicture()` **method into it, to be executed in another separate thread or there's another way?**

Comment: Perhaps [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) could help solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick answer:**

All instances of a class (wxThread is a class) share its methods. So if you want a different `Entry()`, you need a new wxThread-derived class.

**Advice on multithreading:**

While `getPicture()` can be executed in a secondary thread, `showPicture()` should be executed in the main thread because it's the right place to draw into the window. All GUI stuff is strongly recommended to be done **only** in the main thread.

A rare expection is using OpenGL in a secondary thread instead of drawing by OS commands.

The point is that the secondary thread posts a message to the main thread telling "I'm done, image is available".

The new data (image processed) can be put in a placement where the main thread (e.g. the window that is going to draw it) can read it.

Prevent any other thread from accessing the data while the working thread (that for `getPicture()`) is writting, by using `wxCriticalSectionLocker`.

More info at [wxWidgets docs](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_thread.html), [more wxWidgets doc](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_thread.html) an the `thread`sample provided with wxWidgets distribution.

Comment: `The point is that the secondary thread posts a message to the main thread telling "I'm done, image is available". `.  How do I know that the thread has finished its task and ready?

Comment: @LionKing In the secondary thread, after `getPicture()` ends, post the message, just before exiting `Entry()`

Comment: Regarding, `While getPicture() can be executed in a secondary thread, showPicture() should be executed in the main thread because it's the right place to draw into the window`. when putting the `showPicture()` in the main window and `getPicture()` in a thread, the result was that  `showPicture()` doesn't display the current image but displays the previos image

Comment: The window must have a member function to handle the received message from the secondary thread. Use [Bind](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_evt_handler.html#a03cc68ca201fb79c7e837919025be71a). In this fuction is where you call `showPicture()`

Comment: `Use Bind.`, what's the type of event will be used?

Comment: See the thread sample, searching for `wxQueueEvent`. The sample uses old event-tables (e.g. `EVT_THREAD(...)`, You better use Bind(), examples [here](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_events.html#overview_events_bind)